# Plotting a gaussian with a function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

Can someone explain to me why my code is not running correctly ? I have not used python for ages and forgot many things, im baffled as to what is going wrong, pls help.
Here is my code and the result:

```
def my_gaussian(x, mu=0, sigma=1):
    """
    Compute the Gaussian function.

    Parameters
    ----------
    x : float or array
    A single value or an array of values for which the Gaussian will be 
    evaluated.
    mu : optional, float
    mean of the Gaussian distribution
    sigma : optional, float
    square root of the variance of the Gaussian distribution
    
    Returns
    -------
    y : array
        values of the Gaussian distribution for all values of x
    """
    
    #return my_gaussian

    #np.exp(-np.power(x - mu, 2.) / (2 * np.power(sig, 2.)))


    return np.exp((-(x-mu)**2)/((2*sigma)**2))/(np.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma**2))

    x_values = np.linspace(-5, 5, 120)
    for mu, sigma in [(-1, 1), (0, 2), (2, 3)]:
        plt.plot(x_values, my_gaussian(x_values, mu, sigma))

    plt.show()

assert (abs(my_gaussian(0) - 0.3989422804014327) < 1e-7)
assert (abs(my_gaussian(1) - 0.24197072451914337) < 1e-7)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-e7936a624ac1> in <module>
      1 assert (abs(my_gaussian(0) - 0.3989422804014327) < 1e-7)
----> 2 assert (abs(my_gaussian(1) - 0.24197072451914337) < 1e-7)

AssertionError:
```

Comment: For starters your return statement doesn't appear to be properly indented.  And you should provide the entire traceback when possible.

Comment: @Chris I am having trouble with the indentation on stack, i dont know how to tab everything as tab doesnt seem to do its usual function

Comment: try using 4 spaces?

Comment: @Chris But I need to indent it all to replicate my actual code

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your Gaussian function, should be like this:

```py
    return np.exp((-((x - mu)**2)) / (2 * sigma**2)) / (np.sqrt(2 * np.pi * sigma**2))
```